# Can xVal be used for traditional Web forms model?

Tags: asp.net, validation, xval, validationframework

It appears that xVal fits more into a MVC model. Can it be used for traditional Web forms model?

I am currently considering MS Validation block and .NET validation framework. What other validation frameworks can I look into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a webforms port of xval as well that you can find [here](http://xvalwebforms.codeplex.com/). Xval isn't relay a validation framework in it self, but more of a way to link server validation together with client validation so that you don't have to repeat your code. And you do this by using your favorite server side validation framework and your favorite client side validation framework.

Personally I prefer to use [fluent validation](http://www.codeplex.com/FluentValidation) on the server side and jquery validation on the client side. The thing I like about fluent validation is that it decouples you validation from your model in that you don't need any attributes (I don't relay like attribute style validation). And it has support for some pretty advanced validation. If you want to use a attribute style validation framework I would probably suggest [castles](http://www.castleproject.org/ActiveRecord/documentation/v1rc1/manual/validators.html) framework. I have used it in some projects and I think it works pretty good. And it integrates well with xval as well (at least with the mvc version).